# How Are My Python Installations' Command Names Determined, and Can I Change Them?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, python, path

I recently installed 3 versions of Python on my Windows 10 machine: Python 3.8, Python 3.10, and Python 3.11.

I have
[added all of them to Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoDXS.png)
. I have successfully run Python3.8 by typing in `python` in the command line, and Python 3.11 by typing in `python3.11` into the command line. However, when I tried typing in `python3.10` into the command line, it just said [there was no such command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Ks6.png).

I could always use the full filepath to my python installations in all my .bat files, but this got me thinking: **How is the 'python3.11' command name determined**? I went straight to the Python installation directory and searched for 3.11, and the only thing I got was an HTML document named '3.11' in documentation, but there was **no executable file named python3.11**, not even when [I made all hidden files visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZrv5.png)

That also made me wonder if I could change the command name for Python 3.10 to `python3.10`, or even the command name for Python 3.8 to `python3.8`, since there was no executable in the Python 3.11 installation folder that had the name 'python3.11'.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If in doubt, use `where`. For example: `where python`.

Comment: Your image doesn't show the folder containing `python3.10.exe`, please replace it.

Comment: @DanielB `Where` didn't work for me but `gcm py` and `gcm python` worked for me. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/13642249) that mentions it in PS

Comment: Hi, @harrymc, my image was meant to show the file containing python3.11.exe, which does not exist in there. :) Never mind, someone else has already answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python3.11.exe` is not an official executable included within default Windows Python installations. Normally there's just `python3.exe` and `python.exe` when it comes to versioning them. There's a bunch of explantations as to why, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801225/python-or-python3-what-is-the-difference).

As Daniel mentioned in a comment, you can just use `where python3.11` to know where the executable is located. Or you could look for it with an app like [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/). You can use regex like `python[^\\]*\.exe$` (with regular expressions enabled ofc) to find all the Python executables that are in your system.

My bet is that it's a part of a different program. On my Windows, I have for instance `python3.10.exe` as a part of MinGW64 environment that comes with Tartube. It's not in `$PATH` but some other app could easily place that kind of `.exe` in the same directory as its main executables and include that dir in `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question unlike the other dozens of individuals who asked 'but why would you need to do this', or 'try some other way'.